# JPG files uploaded to Dropbox from my Android app using the Dropbox API having missing pixels

Tags: android, image, jpeg, dropbox

I have been using my Android app to save the backup txt files to Dropbox with no issues for the last year.  Today I also added code to upload JPG files from my device to Dropbox, and each photo is missing pixels - usually lower half of picture - they just show up with the lower half all grey.  Seems like part of the picture doesn't upload, but I can't explain why.  I've search and haven't found any reference to this issue on Google or StackOverflow....that makes me scared as every problem I've had so far I've always found someone else who has had the issue and has a fix.  Can't believe I'm the first.....HELP!!!!!!

Example Picture before upload:  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7lHLBiiexXjc0JjbXpmMzZ2MGM/edit?usp=sharing

Example Picture after upload:  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7lHLBiiexXjMVhYeHdJWkZObE0/edit?usp=sharing

```
 private class backupPhotosToDropbox extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {


               FileInputStream inputStream = null;
               try 
               {
                   String extStorageDirectory;
                   extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

                   File file = new File(extStorageDirectory+ "/TAPro2/Photos");

                   File imageList[] = file.listFiles();

                   for(int i=0; i<imageList.length; i++)
                   {
                       inputStream = new FileInputStream(imageList[i]);

                       Entry newEntry = mDBApi.putFile("/Photos/"+ imageList[i].getName(), inputStream, file.length(),null,null);
                           Log.i("DbExampleLog", "The uploaded file's rev is: " + newEntry.rev);
                   }

               }

               catch (DropboxUnlinkedException e) 
               {
                    Log.e("DbExampleLog", "User has unlinked.");
               } 
               catch (DropboxException e) 
               {
                    Log.e("DbExampleLog", "Something went wrong while uploading.");
               } 
               catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
               {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
               }

               if (inputStream != null) 
               {
                   try 
                   {
                       inputStream.close();
                   } 
                   catch (IOException e) {}
               }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Posting the code that handles the upload will be mighty helpful here.

Comment: Please show us some code or we'll never understand what's going on

Comment: Ok,  I'll add the code.  Left it out first as the code works fine for uploading my .txt files so I know the code works.  I'll also upload an example of the jpgs before and after upload.

Answer (score 1):

Yay  - figured out the issue.  instead of using the image.length I was using the original folder.length in the dropbox code.  I changed file.length to image[i].length and now everything is working fine!!